# How to take value in a variable from an input text?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to take the value from text field to a variable for checking a condition
Is it possible in view? I'm using CodeIgniter.

```
 <input type="text" id="student_gen" name="student_gen">
```

Comment: use form submitting method.

Comment: i want to get that variable in the same view page

Comment: you need the `name` attribute in your input else it wont show up in superglobals

Comment: thats ok..how to get value

Comment: You can use `jQuery` here, or still use `php` to submit the form on the same page, then you can run your tests.

Comment: $name=$this->input->post('student_gen');

Answer (score 0):

On form submit you can take value in `javascript` function like:-

```
var x=document.getElementbyId('student_gen').value;
```

If you want to do it on entering text immediately then you can call a function on `onchange="myFunction()"`

and in function you can take value by above method.

Answer (score 0):

In action form set `current_url()` after submit get input in this way
`$this->input->post('student_gen');`

```
if (!$this->input->post('student_gen'))
    echo 'empty field';
elseif ($this->input->post('student_gen') != 'M')
    echo 'wrong value';
```

or You can get and check with jquery

```
$('#student_gen').change(function(){
    if (!$(this).val() || $(this).val() != 'M')
       alert('Wrong or empty value');
});
```

Comment: <form name="whatelse" action="<?=current_url()?>" method="post" >

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#student_gen").change(function(){
    var x = $("#student_gen").val();
      if(x=='condition'){
       code..
      } 
  });
});
```

or javaScript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("student_gen").value;
    if(x=='condition'){
      code..
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="student_gen" name="student_gen" onchange="myFunction()">
```